# Why is the parent component not re-rendering?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have data that is stored in Vuex store. I access them from the parent component:

```
computed: {
...mapGetters({
  items: 'favoriteDocumentsWithFolders',
}),
```

},

In the child component, I access the store and change this data, but the re-render of the parent component does not occur. Why?

Comment: Which vue version are you using ? and how are changing the data?

Comment: It's unknown why a thing that's supposed to work doesn't work in your case. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.

Comment: "I access the store and change this data".  You need to show your code for this as it sounds extremely relevant to your problem.

Comment: vue version - 2.6.9 
In the child component, I call the store's method moveFavoritesDocument:

`await this.$store.dispatch('moveFavoritesDocument', {
          favoriteId: itemId,
          newfolderid: folderId
        });`

In this method, a request is made to the server and the server changes the data. Next, in the same child component method, I read the data:
 
`await this.$store.dispatch('getFavoriteDocumentsWithFolders', {
          section: FAVORITES_SECTION_PRIVATE
        });`

As a result, the value of the variable in the storage changes - favoriteDocumentsWithFolders